# How to implement lookahead in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have sample data as

```
with temp as (
select DATE("2019-01-02") as time_stamp, "3" as id
union all
select DATE("2019-01-03") as time_stamp, "6" as id
union all
select DATE("2019-01-04") as time_stamp, "5" as id
union all
select DATE("2019-01-05") as time_stamp, "11" as id
)
select time_stamp, id
from temp
```

I want to implement lookahead logic in bigQuery, meaning if todays date is `"2019-01-02"` then I want all the data for next `N days` (assume `N = 3` for simplicity).

For the above example, it would return IDs `6,5 and 11` if I run on `2019-01-02`. (logic :: capture all IDs for next 3 days from 2019-01-02)

I want to implement this for a given date range with lookahead window `N=3` days.So if I run it for `fromDate=2019-01-02` and `toDate=2019-01-03` then I want 2 sets of results. For `date=2019-01-02` I will need `IDs 6,5,11` and for `date=2019-01-03` I will need `IDs 5 and 11`.

So the output would be

```
processed_date, id
2019-01-02, 6
2019-01-02, 5
2019-01-02, 11
2019-01-03, 5
2019-01-03, 11
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured a way to do it but I am not sure if its efficient. Here is my SQL code -

```
with temp as (
select DATE("2019-01-02") as time_stamp, "3" as id
union all
select DATE("2019-01-03") as time_stamp, "6" as id
union all
select DATE("2019-01-04") as time_stamp, "5" as id
union all
select DATE("2019-01-05") as time_stamp, "11" as id
union all
select DATE("2019-01-08") as time_stamp, "13" as id
),
date_ranges as ( select DATE("2019-01-02") as fromDate , DATE("2019-01-03") as toDate , 3 as window_length ) ,
distinct_dates as (
SELECT day , (select window_length as window_length from date_ranges) window_length
FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY((select fromDate from date_ranges), (select toDate from date_ranges), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS day
)
-- choose your columns from here
select * , date_diff(time_stamp, day, day) as date_difference 
from temp
cross join distinct_dates 
where date_diff(time_stamp, day, day) > 0 and date_diff(time_stamp, day, day) <= (select window_length as window_length from date_ranges)
order by day
```